# JQuery get values for all inputs in a div

Tags: jquery, html, input, multiple-instances

I have many of these multiple choice selections in a control panel, and I wish to get the data entered into the text fields using JQuery. Preferably the format would be Question, AnswerOpt1, AnswerOpt2.... I have tried the code supplied below, and some variations of it, but have been unsuccessful.

HTML

```
<div class="formRow">
    <label>Multiple Choice: </label>
    <div class="formRight">
        Question: <input type="text" class="MCQuestion" />
    </div>
    <div class="formRight MCAns">
        Answer Option1: <input type="text" class="MCAnswer"/>
    </div>
    <div class="formRight MCAns">
        Answer Option2: <input type="text" class="MCAnswer"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div><a href="#" id="Save">Save</a></div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#Save").on("click",function() {
    $(".MCQuestion").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()!=""){
            $(this).parent().find(".MCAnswer").each(function(){
                $('#log').after($(this).val());
            });
        }
    });
return false;
});
```

Comment: use append instead of after

Answer (score 4):

When you're traversing up to the parent element of `.MCQuestion` you're only getting to `.formRight`. Use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to go up to the `.formRow` then back down to each `.MCAnswer`:

```
$("#Save").on("click",function() {
    $(".MCQuestion").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()!=""){
            $(this).closest(".formRow").find(".MCAnswer").each(function(){
                $('#log').after($(this).val());
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$('#log').after($(this).val());
```

with

```
$('#log').append($(this).val() + ' ');
```

**EDIT**

Also this line is a problem

```
$(this).parent().find(".MCAnswer")
```

replace with

```
$(this).closest('.formRow').find(".MCAnswer")
```

`.parent` gets the immediate an parent of the element in question. But elements with class `MCAnswers` are present inside the `formRow` element and not the immediate parent.

Also a better idea to cache your selectors when using it multiple times.

**Code**

```
$("#Save").on("click", function () {
    $(".MCQuestion").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            value = $this.val();
        if (value != "") {
            $this.closest('.formRow').find(".MCAnswer").each(function () {
                $('#log').append(value + ' ');
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cWeBK/)**

Comment: Thanks, I have done that! But this doesn't really help my issue?

Comment: @JoshLukeBlease.. Check ediut